# How to add transition on mouseover and mouseout event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am changing the picture on mouseover and mouseout events. I wanna add transition in between the changing the picture. How to add it?

```
onmouseover-
{document.getElementById("img1").src="images/css-logo.png"}

onmouseout-
{document.getElementById("img1").src="images/html-logo.png"}

html-
<img id="img1" src="images/html-logo.png"  onmouseover="setNewImage()" onmouseout="setOldImage()" alt="logos">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS and avoid using the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events entirely... It is probably more efficient. The example below uses the `CSS` `:hover` to change the background image, while also applying a transition effect.

If you really want to use the `mouseover` event, you could change use `.css("background-image", ...)` to change the background image rather than have it set in CSS.

Hope this helps

---

## Demo

```css
img {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF');
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

img:hover {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000');
}
```

```html
<img>
```